# WP term associated data?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a wordpress taxonomy, lets class it class, among class I have various terms.

Each of the terms has data like name,slug etc. I'm well aware how to fetch that, however terms also have a select box drop down called 'best buy', and I have no idea how to get that.

I noticed that there is a custom field called 'best_buy_classes' but I'm still lost.

I would just like to get the value of the data in that select box connected to the term and I have no idea how.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're asking is how to echo a custom post type and the [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) for each post.

To grab the custom post type just use a traditional wordpress loop ie.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'CUSTOMPOSTTYPENAME', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Within this you can grab your [grab your meta_data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) (custom fields) by using this syntax

> $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);

I strongly suggest you do a big read of the wordpress codex and check out the [Getting Started Section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress).

Hope I could help!